# How to fix Prolog Type error: 'callable' expected, found '1'

Tags: prolog

Here's my source:

```
and(A,B) :- A,B.
and(A,B) :- A=:=1, B=:=1.
```

I expect to use `and` with either boolean or numeric (where 1 is true and 0 is false) inputs and get the proper results.

I run the script and write this query:

`A=0, B=1, and(A,B).`

But I'm getting this error:

`ERROR: and/2: Type error: 'callable' expected, found '1'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Prolog standard defines a `callable/1` built-in predicate. This is a type-checking predicate that is true when its argument is bound to a callable term. Thus, you can write e.g.:

```
and(A,B) :- callable(A), callable(B), call((A,B)).
and(A,B) :- A=:=1, B=:=1.
```